# Is there a way to add items to notification center through terminal or other means?

Tags: macos, notifications

I'm wanting to add specific Websites to notification center (the stack exchange network, for example) and I want to be able to see various notifications that the website would send me.

Is there a way to add a website to be checked in notification center via terminal or some sort of script that can be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a notification from the command line with this [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier) utility. Getting the notification data off a site can be fairly involved, requires at least some decent scripting and/or web coding knowledge, and is probably a better question to pose on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

The basic outline of such a script would be:

- Open a site
- Send login data if necessary
- Scrape the page for the data you need (unless you're lucky and the site has a JSON or XML API, in which case you can parse that)
- Send the appropriate data via the terminal-notify utility

This sort of thing may be more common in the future though, as Safari 6 and Mountsin Lion add support for [web notifications](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/), which will allow a site to display notifications, *when Safari has an open tab for that site*.

Support for this needs to be coded into the site however, so it's not really an end user solution I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok this is helpful. Now I just need to figure out how to write a quick program to run in the background and check for new notifications every minute or so. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

If you dont’t want to script anything, try this little menu bar application called [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x). I use it for all notifications related to the StackExchange network.

Also, it might me a good idea to first check if the website in question has a RSS feed for the notifications you want.

In case you want to write a scraper, first have a look at [possible options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping) regarding languages and modules. I personally have used [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) with Perl, and loved [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) with Ruby.

Comment: This combined with [Hiss](http://collect3.com.au/hiss/) is doing what I originally set out to do. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Shameless plug: If you find this answer useful, please consider marking this answer as 'accepted'. Thanks!

Comment: I think I might, but CanuckSkier's answer is more general and I might need to create a generalized app for other sites in the future.