# get a notification when my machine is pinged

Tags: macos, network, notifications, ping

I'd like to be able to be notified in any way (sound, notification, growl, etc) when someone pings my machine.

Is that possible?

Comment: I would probably have a pair of shell scripts. One running tcpdump and grepping for "ICMP echo request" and writing to a pipe and another script reading from the pipe and doing the rate limiting (so a ping flood doesn’t occupy your speakers for days) and calling [terminal-notifier](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61943/is-there-a-way-to-add-items-to-notification-center-through-terminal-or-other-mea). However, I've done a fair amount of shell scripting, so you might not want this implementation if you're not handy with light scripting tools and syntax.

Comment: This is useful to detect as early as possible when someone at the other end of the Internet will next fire an `nmap` against your Mac and finally try to penetrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) may have the feature you want. It allows you to set up rules on network traffic, both inbound and outbound, mostly for blocking unwanted traffic, but I believe it can perform arbitrary actions such as notification for specific rules and types of traffic like ICMP pings.

There's a trial version that you can use to test.

I have no affiliation with Little Snitch or the company behind it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a well tested perl script to enable this kind of cheap attack detector:
[sonar perl script](https://github.com/dazuelos/sonar)

The sound will change along the logarithmic level of probes (ping).

From an original idea of [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike).