# How to make a message appear on the screen?

Tags: macos, command-line, script, dialog

I'm trying to set up a kind of **intercom** system between Mac, Windows, and Linux boxes at home.

**Question**: How can I make an arbitrary message appear on the graphical screen of Mac OS X?

For instance, I'm looking for a command such as:

```
$ show-message "Time for dinner!"
```

which shows *Time for dinner!* on the graphical screen, maybe in a dialog box.

Comment: I think you're going to have a very hard time to do this cross-platform. Windows has `netsend`, but a quick Google search shows there's no easy equivalent on the Mac. Growl has some network announcement capabilities and is available for [Mac](http://growl.info/) and [Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/) so maybe that's a possibility.

Comment: Just did it! `kdialog` and `cocoaDialog` over `ssh` do the job in Linux and Mac respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be fairly trivial with ssh to gain access to the Mac and then run whatever command you prefer.

1. [Is there a way to add items to notification center through terminal or other means?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61943/) - which covers [SeNotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x) and the more general purpose [terminal notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier) which both leverage OS X's notification center app for the GUI.
2. [How can I trigger a Notification Center notification from an AppleScript or shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/) - which covers both AppleScript and Terminal scripts - either of which will work when called from ssh from Linux, Mac or Windows remotely. It also adds in [Growl2](http://itunes.apple.com/be/app/growl/id467939042?mt=12) as a GUI for messaging on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

bmike provided a link at which mivk suggests another quite lightweight solution: [cocoaDialog](http://mstratman.github.io/cocoadialog/) (Mac OS X 10.4+)